# Checking Expiration Date of SSL with PHP Curl

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to get the expiration date of a SSL through PHP Curl.

My code is:

```
<?php
$curlSES=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_URL, "https://expired.badssl.com/");
curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);
curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
$result=curl_exec($curlSES);

//echo $result;
$certInfo   = curl_getinfo($curlSES, CURLINFO_CERTINFO);
//[0]['Expire date'])
echo print_r($certInfo[0]['Expire date'],true);
echo print_r($certInfo, true);
curl_close($curlSES);
?>
```

The URL I have inserted has a no-longer valide certificate due to expiration.

If a browse it through browser I can see the expiration date while with CURL above the `$certInfo` array is empty and it doesn't give me the expiration date at all.

Can I affirm that, if I am expecting a certificate but the `$certInfo` array is empty  the URL has no SSL valid, anymore?

I am little confused due to I was expecting an expiration date in CURL even if the certificate has expired (and not empty certificate information as I got)

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your script is that curl is automatically verifying the certificate and denies the connection if not valid.
To ignore the validation you need to use `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false

```
curl_setopt($curlSES, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Then you should be able to get the expired certificate and together with that also the expiration date.